# MySQL create temporary table

Tags: mysql

Cannot understand why this create temporary table is not working.. Can anyone suggest..?

```
create temporary table if not exists table2 AS (select unix_timestamp(concat(delivery_date, ' ', str_to_date(delivery_time,'%h:%i%p'))) as timestamp, id from fruit.order_delivery_orders where calendar_id is not null);
```

It gets an error "query interrupted".

This query works fine -

```
select unix_timestamp(concat(delivery_date, ' ', str_to_date(delivery_time,'%h:%i%p'))) as timestamp, id from fruit.order_delivery_orders where calendar_id is not null
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: yes.. I am using mysql workbench.. it says "query interrupted"..

Comment: That means the query is taking too long. Is there an index on `calendar_id`?

Comment: ok let me create one..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354229/query-execution-was-interrupted-error-1317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please used below syntax. May this help you.

```
 CREATE TABLE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] table_name AS SELECT column_names FROM table_name_2 WHERE condition;
```

Comment: I thought at first it was due to the parentheses around `select`, but I tried it and it works.

Comment: could be a data issue then?

Comment: But this answer don't create a temporary table. Or am I wrong?