# Frequent 'Query execution was interrupted error code 1317' error for select query through elasticsearch java API

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch

I understand that there is a question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354229/query-execution-was-interrupted-error-1317) about the error `Query execution was interrupted error code 1317`, but I am not sure if my issue and the one discussed in that question are the same. So, here's some background:

I am reading from a MySQL database and pushing the data into an Elasticsearch database every minute. So, I already have one connection open and active to pull the data from MySQL. Now when I am opening another connection for inserting data using the Elasticsearch Java API, I am constantly getting the interruption exception below.  There are about 49 free connections and I am providing about 3 GB of RAM for running the Java program which inserts the data.

```
 [main] 2015-05-12 14:30:41 com.db.exceptions.DBUncategorizedException: DatabaseSourceImplV2::  selectPrepSQLStmt [DATABASE]  Query execution was interrupted error code 1317 error state 70100
at com.db.exceptions.SQLExceptionTranslator.translateFromDBErrorStates(SQLExceptionTranslator.java:154)
at com.db.exceptions.SQLExceptionTranslator.createDBException(SQLExceptionTranslator.java:85)
at com.db.DatabaseSourceImplV2.selectPrepSQLStmt(DatabaseSourceImplV2.java:927)
at com.db.DatabaseSourceImplV2.select(DatabaseSourceImplV2.java:556)
at com.db.DatabaseSourceImplV2.select(DatabaseSourceImplV2.java:328)
at com.es.dao.ArgusESDAO.getF5HttpRequests(ArgusESDAO.java:363)
at com.es.F5HttpRequestToES1.pushToES(F5HttpRequestToES1.java:150)
at com.es.F5HttpRequestToES1.main(F5HttpRequestToES1.java:93)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query execution was interrupted
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:868)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1351)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2333)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1443)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1777)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1403)
at com.db.DatabaseSourceImplV2.selectPrepSQLStmt(DatabaseSourceImplV2.java:922)
... 5 more
```

It was suggested to make sure the tables I am querying are indexed. My tables are indexed and I have tested by running very light `SELECT` queries to make sure I have enough time for query execution. So, I am not really sure what is happening here. Any idea if I am missing something basic here?

Updating the question in response to Val's comments:

1. My hosting provider doesn't kill it as it's running fine for a connection that's already created.
2. My DB connection default time out is about 8 hours, so no problem there. It's my company's server, so they have huge amounts of data coming in every second and very heavy queries running every second.

3. My query is heavy, but there shouldn't be a problem as it's already being handled well by one connection.

My query runs for 0.078 seconds when I run it in an SQL command line.

Comment: There could be several reasons, among which: 1) your hosting provider kills your query if it lasts too long, 2) your DB connection settings use a default timeout that is too short, 3) your query is too heavy... Can you show your query and the DB connection settings you're using? Have you tried to execute your query directly from the mysql command-line and how long does it take?

Comment: @Val I have updated the question. Please check it.